# How to make a flattening function for linq object (Linq To Entities for mysql)?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am upgrading an old program and using linq for basic select, so that I can learn linq in process. 
I have a repetitive task of just showing data from various join is grid view,
Below is a sample

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using ( vavestockModel.vavestockEntities db = new vavestockModel.vavestockEntities())
    {
        var prod = (from p in db.products select p);
        var prodd = (from p in db.productdetails select p);
        var prode = (from p in db.product_extra_data select p);
        var join1 = (from p in prod
                     join
                         pd in prodd
                         on p.PrStyle equals pd.StyleCode
                     select new {pr=p,prd=pd }).ToList();
        var join2 = (from p in prod
                     join
                         pd in prodd
                         on p.PrStyle equals pd.StyleCode
                     select new { p.PrShow,p.PrPrice,pd.I_EAN_51,pd.I_EAN_50 }).ToList();
        var join3 = (from p in prod
                     join
                         pd in prodd
                         on p.PrStyle equals pd.StyleCode
                     select new { flattenmodel(p),flattenmodel(pd) }).ToList();

        Response.Write(join1);
        GridView1.DataSource = join1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}

??object flattenmodel(vavestockModel.vavestockEntities en)//? here i want to pass any table row
{
    string[] toren;
    //foreach (var item in en.)
    //{

    //}
    return toren;
}
```

join2 can be bound to gridview while join1 cant because they return entity object. Since I have to select all columns writing all names repetitively for so many tables is not a wise choice hence i want to write a function that returns the flattened data.

But I am finding it difficult to proceed. My difficulty is coming because I don't know what should be returned and passed as parameters in this case. Can some one point me in right direction to proceed?

Comment: Are your Domain objects just POCOs?Which version of EntityFramework do you use?

Comment: I am using EF5, and they are classes generated by Framework itself.

Comment: Instead you should learn navigation properties and projection, that will help you write better queries without joins, you are not supposed to use joins in Entity Framework.

Comment: What exactly is the problem  with your entity objects?They cannot be serialized?Also,do they inherit from EntityObject ?

Comment: There is no problem, Only thing I want to do is not to write all column name that I want to select, instead create a function that return all columns value so that it can be bound to gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all properties of an object through `System.Reflection`  here is an example how you can get values from all properties and store them in `List` and than you can assign this `List` as datasource.

```
Entities ent = new Entities();
var data = (from x in ent.Employees where x.Id == 1 select x).FirstOrDefault();
List<string> list = ConvertToList(data);

public List<string> ConvertToList(object obj)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        PropertyInfo[] pinfo = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var info in pinfo)
        {
            if (info.GetValue(obj) != null)
                list.Add(info.GetValue(obj, null).ToString());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

**Edit**

You can also return a `DataTable`from anonymous object.

```
public DataTable ConvertToDataTable(IEnumerable<dynamic> obj)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (dynamic item in obj)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            PropertyInfo[] pinfo = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var info in pinfo)
            {
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains(info.Name))
                    dt.Columns.Add(info.Name, info.PropertyType);

                var val= info.GetValue(item, null);
                dr[info.Name] = val;

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Here is how you will call it

```
Entities ent = new Entities();
var data = (from x in ent.Employees where x.Id == 1 select x).FirstOrDefault();
DataTable dt=ConvertToDataTable(data);
```

Comment: No. it will just convert it into list, I dont want list but an anonymous class that has all the values from both the classes.

Comment: In your question you mentioned that you are returning array of strng in flattenmodel function. ?

Comment: @Ratna It will contain all values of an object passed to it you can modify it and pass multiple objects and get values from every object and convert into list and than make that list source of gridview.

Comment: but I am not able to bind it because every row contains a list,

Comment: OK than you can make a datatable and add rows in it and than bind this table.

Comment: The datatable I want to generate automatically in the function itself so that I do not have to write columns names each time.

Comment: Yes the code i have provided is doing that it is getting properties name which will be column name and than getting values which will be value for that column.

Comment: Not compiling due to error-->No overload for method 'GetValue' takes '1' arguments

Comment: yes add a second parameter null as i have done `info.GetValue(obj, null)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80168/discussion-between-ratna-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Comment: This method dosent work, but converting to datatable works, Ahmed can you replace your current answer with the new one that you gave me over chat so that i can accept your answer?